# When I use the Zoom tools of matlab how i detect if i use mouse scroll?

Tags: matlab, zooming, matlab-figure, matlab-gui

I developed this code to see if the user did zoom in or zoom out on a figure in matlab

```
function demo3

MainFig = figure;
x = sin(theta) + 0.75*rand(1,300);
y = cos(theta) + 0.75*rand(1,300);
a = 40;
hs=scatter(x,y,a,'MarkerEdgeColor',[0 .5 .5],...
'MarkerFaceColor',[0 .7 .7],...
'LineWidth',1.5);        
h = zoom;

set(MainFig, 'WindowScrollWheelFcn', @figure1_WindowScrollWheelFcn);
set(h, 'ActionPostCallback', @mypostcallback);

function mypostcallback(h, eventdata)
disp('INFO: Direction')
h2 = zoom;
get(h2,'Direction')

function figure1_WindowScrollWheelFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if eventdata.VerticalScrollCount > 0
    disp ('Scrool Up ')
else
    disp ('Scrool Down ')
end
```

The problem is if I run the code and I use a mouse scroll the information is correct and detect if i do scroll up or down. But if I use the Zoom tools and press in zoom in the information is correct relatively to direction but if I use the mouse scroll up and down the information is the same:

> INFO: Direction
>
> ans =
>
> in

I need a code that detects if I do a zoom in or zoom out either with the Zoom tool or with the scrool mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
set(h, 'ActionPostCallback', @mypostcallback);
set(h, 'ActionPreCallback', @myprecallback);

function myprecallback(h, eventdata)
set(h, 'UserData', {eventdata.Axes.XLim, eventdata.Axes.YLim})

function mypostcallback(h, eventdata)
old_lims = get(h, 'UserData');
old_d = cellfun(@diff, old_lims);
new_d = [diff(eventdata.Axes.XLim), diff(eventdata.Axes.YLim)];
disp('INFO: Direction')
if all(old_d == new_d)
    disp('No change');
elseif  all(old_d-new_d <= 0)
    disp('Out')
elseif all(old_d-new_d >= 0)
    disp('In')
else
    disp('oops, did not expect this!')
end
```

This saves the `axes` limits just before the zoom and compares it with the limits after the zoom. If they're bigger, we zoomed out, if they're smaller, we zoomed in.